# How can I call an Observable with timer inside of an Observable with typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a http POST call in Angular which takes about 15-20 seconds to complete.
In my backend I provide a computed value for a progressbar of the post call in frontend.

Now I want to make http GET calls every 250ms after POST call is initiated until the post call is completed.

I took a look an the operaters of Rxjs but could't come to a solution how to combine/pipe them correctly(eg. timer or interval)

This is my current code:

```
// this is the Observable which does the post call when subscribing
const x = this.apiService.importBackUp(this.backupList);

x.subscribe(); // here I want to subscribe to my GET call every 250ms until completion
```

apiService.ts:

```
importBackUp(backup: BackupList[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.API_URL + '/Settings/import', backup)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('Import Backup', null))
      );
}

getProgress(): Observable<number> {
    return this.httpClient.get<number>(this.API_URL + '/Settings/progress')
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('Get Import Progress', null))
      );
}
```

Comment: Did you try `.pipe(interval(250))`?

Comment: you mean `const x = this.apiService.importBackUp(this.backupList).pipe(interval(250), this.apiService.getProgress());` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
interval(250).pipe(
        mergeMap(()=>this.apiService.getProgress()),
        tap(progress=>do you process update ....),
        takeUntil(this.apiService.importBackUp(this.backupList))
        ).subscribe()
```

or

```
this.apiService.importBackUp(this.backupList).pipe(
withLatestFrom(
    interval(250).pipe(
    switchMap(()=>this.apiService.getProgress()),
    tap(progress=>do you process update ....),
    )
)
.subscribe()
```